# Do not update css when draggable is disabled

Tags: jquery

On this fiddle when I click disable'Li Point1' the text ebcomes greyed out http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjsfiddlenetuser/Q9sHz/14/

Can the original styling of the element be maintained(not greyed out) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three options.  You can either remove the styles from jquery-ui.css for `.ui-state-disabled`, you can override the style in your own custom style sheet, or you can flag the altered properties as `!important`.

**Remove Styles**

To remove the styles, you need to edit `jquery-ui.css` and look for the `.ui-state-disabled` rule (in jQuery 1.7.2, it's on line 262).  Remove all the styles within there (you'll see three, `opacity`, `filter`, and `background-image`.

The disadvantage of this is that if you ever update jQuery and get a new CSS file to go with it, you'll lose your edits.

**Add Own Stylesheet**

You can add your own rule for `.ui-state-disabled` and change the style of disabled elements.  Since `ui-state-disabled` is used for everything in jQuery that is disabled, I'd suggest defining your rule as exclusive to `li`, or set a class on your `ul` and define the styles for that specifically.

```
<ul class=".noStyleDisableDrag">
    ...
</ul>

.noStyleDisableDrag .ui-state-disabled {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: none;
    background-image: inherit;
}
```

**Flag as !important**

You can also add the opacity, filter, and background-image style to other rules that define how that particular item is supposed to appear and use the `!important` flag.  It isn't the most recommended way of doing things, though, because it can wreak havoc on your CSS style debugging if you forget that you flagged it, but it is an option.  To do that, you simply style your `li` as such:

```
li {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    filter: none !important;
    background-image: (whatever you want, or none) !important;
}
```

Note that in this case, if you aren't setting a background image on the draggable, then you don't need the line to set the background-image; just set `opacity` and `filter` to be un-overridden.  Also note that these CAN be overridden by JavaScript, so they aren't set in stone.

---

Of the three, you may need to use a combination.  My suggestions is to use your own custom stylesheet to override the `opacity` and `filter` properties.  If you are using background-images, you may need to use `!important` to keep it from being removed by the `ui-state-disabled` rule.  But use the `!important` flag as sparingly as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Line 262 jquery-ui.css remove the filter and the opacity line

```
 .ui-state-disabled, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-disabled,
 .ui-widget-header .ui-state-disabled {
     background-image: none; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the disable button adds a CSS class `ui-state-disabled` to the element. Just overwrite the styles for that class.

```
.ui-state-disabled { opacity:1; }
```

Comment: This won't work in IE8; you need to override the `filter` property as well.

Comment: @saluce I just tested on IE8 without filter property set and it seems to be fine. I'll add it though just in case....